# SublimeText: autoindent on save?

Tags: sublimetext, auto-indent, autoformatting

I'm wondering if there is any way to autoformat code in ST3 for a specified event (here on save). For instance, I would like Sublime to format my code each time I save my code (and for any languages).

Is there a plugin for that? Or can I create a shortcut in config to trigger this process?

I'll appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your for your help jsnprtr but I found another solution.
Unfortunately, with ST3, I was unable to run save command in a macro. I tried to design a tiny plugin but I didn't succeed.

I found this plugin which allows to run multiple commands on a custom shortcut: https://github.com/jisaacks/ChainOfCommand

With it, I am now able to format my code on save: I just run indent and save commands :)

If some guys have other tricks to improve autoformatting when writing code with ST, I'll appreciate their contribution ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin which will format PHP, JS, HTML, CSS and Python which is Available through package manager: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CodeFormatter

If you want to format the code on every save, you could create a macro, then bind that macro to ctrl+s. Something like the following should do:

```
[
    {
        "command": "code_formatter",
        "args": null
    },
    {
        "command": "save",
        "args": null
    }
]
```

Save this as "indent_on_save.sublime-snippet" in your Packages/User/ directory (Easily open this dir by choosing Preferences -> Browse Packages in Sublime Text).

You can then re-bind ctrl+s to use this snippet by going to Preference -> Key Bindings - User and adding the following:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+s"],
    "command": "run_macro_file",
    "args":{"file": "Packages/User/indent_on_save.sublime-macro"}
}
```

There are probably other plugins in package manager which will format other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "reindent on save" package:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Reindent%20on%20save

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.